# How to render image from Firebase without rebuilding?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to implement profile image picking in my flutter app using Firebase Storage. I use image_picker to get the image and upload it to Firebase, get the download link and add the download link to the `imgsrc` field in the cloud firestore, from where I can render the NetworkImage.

```
Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              buildImage(),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 5,
                right: 5,
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: showPhotoAlertDialog,
                    child: buildEditIcon(Color(0xff407bff))),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

How can I get the default `Icons.person` kind image for when the user has no profile image, and get the image from the database otherwise?
The code I'm using right now is as follows:

```
Widget buildImage() {
    return CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(loggedInUser.imgsrc ??
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.945f33b643f2ceffcdae90fb57c61854?rik=XcI0SYBgSefoCA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fgetdrawings.com%2ffree-icon-bw%2fanonymous-avatar-icon-19.png&ehk=5n%2buJG66CeLQZsmhaMt8gag5rXuM3TdebAL6W35K1E4%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[350],
      radius: 100,
    );
  }
```

I created an Alert Dialog widget to choose whether to choose the image from camera or from the gallery.

```
showPhotoAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Upload from"),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              imageFromCamera()
                  .then((value) => uploadFile())
                  .whenComplete(() => postSource());
              setState(() {});                               ----->
            },
            child: Text("Upload from camera"),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              imageFromGallery().then((value) => uploadFile());
              postSource();
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text("Upload from gallery"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

To upload the image to storage and post the source to cloud firestore, I use the following methods:

```
Future uploadFile() async {
    if (file == null) return;

    final fileName = path.basename(file!.path);
    final destination = 'files/$fileName';

    task = FirebaseApi.uploadFile(destination, file!);
    setState(() {});

    if (task == null) return;

    final snapshot = await task!.whenComplete(() {});
    urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    print('Download-Link: $urlDownload');
  }

  postSource() async {
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    await firebaseFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .update({'imgsrc': urlDownload});
  }
```

The link gets uploaded properly and I'm able to get the link in my `NetworkImage`, but it doesn't get rendered immediately. I have to close the parent drawer and open it again to get it. I call `setState(){}` as well after posting the source, but it doesn't make any difference. How can I get the image without having to close and open the drawer?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You also have to update image in model class or in this imgsrc also just add this line above setState in onPressed of TextButton.

```
loggedInUser.imgsrc = urlDownload;
```

Comment: Didn't work. Its still the same